# Mongodb group by a nested field

Tags: mongodb

```
db.logs.aggregate([{$match: { _device: { $in: devices }, takenTimestamp: {$gt: 1547650800 } }}, { $lookup: { 
        from: "users", 
        localField: "_deviceTakenByUser", 
        foreignField: "_id", 
        as: "user" 
    }}, { $project: { _id: 0, user: { email: 1 }}}  ])
```

I know want to get distinct values from the user email, is it possible to do so? Can I do it with grouping?

Comment: Share your sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your `$lookup`, `user` is a list of users.

You can do an `$unwind` to  split it

And then use a `$group` an the `email` field to have a list of all the emails

```
...
{
    "$unwind": "$user"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$user.email" 
    }
}
```